# React Native w/ Expo: Axios post works on emulator, but not on physical device

Tags: react-native, axios, expo, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to upload an image and some data to my API with Axios on my Expo app. Here's the code:

```js
// api.ts
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://999.999.999.999/api', // <-- my cloud server ip
  responseType: 'json'
})

export default api
```

```js
// register.ts
import FormData from 'form-data'  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data
import api from '../services/api'

const options = { headers: 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }

export const register = async (formData: FormData): Promise<boolean> => {
  try {
    const response = api.post<{ error: boolean, data: string }>(
      '/authentication/register',
      formData,
      options
    )
    return Boolean(response.data?.data)
  } catch (error) {
    return false
  }
}
```

I'm also using the `expo-image-picker` and appending the result to `FormData`:

```js
const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({})

if (result.cancelled) {
  return
}

const personalPhotoUriParts = result.uri.split('.')
const personalPhotoFileType = personalPhotoUriParts[personalPhotoUriParts.length - 1]

const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('email', 'teste@mail.com')
formData.appent('password', '123456')

formData.append('personal_photo', {
  uri: result.uri,
  name: `personal_photo.${personalPhotoFileType}`,
  type: `image/${personalPhotoFileType}`
})

register(formData) // from register.ts
```

All the things work as expected on the emulator, send and print from PHP API body content I get:

```html
// var_dump($_POST);
Array [
  "email": "test@mail.com",
  "password": "123456"
]

// var_dump($_FILES)
Object {
  "personal_photo": Object {
    "error": 0,
    "name": "document_photo.jpg",
    "size": 135327,
    "tmp_name": "/tmp/php5o11qT",
    "type": "image/jpg",
  }
}
```

But when I try to send it from a physical device, I get an empty body on both cases:

```html
// var_dump($_POST);
Array []

// var_dump(get_file_contents('php://input'));
// nothing

// var_dump($_FILES);
Array []
```

My bet is on `FormData`, I was using other API routes without problems (on physical device), but when I had to use `multipart/form-data` I've got this problem. For me, does not make sense since the same API worked with React JS (WEB), Postman, and RN w/ Expo on emulator.

Comment: Have you tried changing your URL to https just to see? Are you not seeing any errors anywhere, i.e. the post is completing but with no data being returned? Can you confirm the POST is received by the cloud server and just the response is being misinterpreted by the client? Or do you think the request isn't making it?

Comment: The request is made, if I inspect the network, I can see all the data being sent to the server, but on the server, printing all possible inputs nothing is shown. I can't use HTTPS right now because I haven't a domain provider yet. But I doubt this is the cause, I would get a network error instead (no errors are prompted and the server returns 200 status).

Comment: I'm thinking in get the base64 and then decode to a file on the server, I already tried to eject (expo sdk 40), without success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to enable on your Android Manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

your problem is on Android or iOS device ?

Comment: I'm having a problem on an android device, btw, how to enable this, I'm using Expo on a Managed Workflow, and I have no access to `.android` and `.ios` folders